# ¿ Como subir un archivo al usar input type="file" en WebView?

Tags: javascript, android, html5, webview, webview-android

Tengo un proyecto Android que visualiza una pagina web mediante WebView. Si entro a la pagina mediante cualquier navegador hay un botón que al pulsarlo me sube unos archivos.
El problema es que la pagina web dentro del contenedor de WebView no hace nada. Parece que no reconoce el: input type = 'file'

```
<input type="file" multiple accept=".jpeg,.jpg,.pdf" id="MyFiles" name="MyFiles" onchange="vArchivos(this.files);" />
```

¿ Como puedo hacer que WebView trabaje con el  ?

Answer (score 4):

Para manejar la subida de archivos en el webview, se requiere implementar cierta lógica dentro de tu WebChromeClient. Es decir, enlazar la subida de archivos de la manera tradicional de android con tu webview. Para esto, puedes ayudarte del método `onShowFileChooser`.

```
mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        ............

        //For Android API >= 21 (5.0 OS)
        @Override
        public boolean onShowFileChooser(WebView webView, ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePathCallback, WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams fileChooserParams) {
            uploadMessageAboveL = filePathCallback;
            openImageChooserActivity();
            return true;
        }

    });

private void openImageChooserActivity() {
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
    i.setType("image/*");
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i, "Image Chooser"), FILE_CHOOSER_RESULT_CODE);
}
```

Además, dependiendo del `minSdkVersion` que estes manejando, tienes que manejar las versiones, generalmente para versiones menores a 5.0. Luego recibirlo en el método

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == FILE_CHOOSER_RESULT_CODE) {
        if (null == uploadMessage && null == uploadMessageAboveL) return;
        Uri result = data == null || resultCode != RESULT_OK ? null : data.getData();
        if (uploadMessageAboveL != null) {
            onActivityResultAboveL(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        } else if (uploadMessage != null) {
            uploadMessage.onReceiveValue(result);
            uploadMessage = null;
        }
    }
}
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
private void onActivityResultAboveL(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    if (requestCode != FILE_CHOOSER_RESULT_CODE || uploadMessageAboveL == null)
        return;
    Uri[] results = null;
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        if (intent != null) {
            String dataString = intent.getDataString();
            ClipData clipData = intent.getClipData();
            if (clipData != null) {
                results = new Uri[clipData.getItemCount()];
                for (int i = 0; i < clipData.getItemCount(); i++) {
                    ClipData.Item item = clipData.getItemAt(i);
                    results[i] = item.getUri();
                }
            }
            if (dataString != null)
                results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(dataString)};
        }
    }
    uploadMessageAboveL.onReceiveValue(results);
    uploadMessageAboveL = null;
}
```

Te dejo algunos links donde puedes encontrar más detalle sobre esto.
- https://programmer.group/solutions-for-uploading-files-from-android-webview.html
- https://www.hellojava.com/a/62113.html
- http://michael-huang.logdown.com/posts/1660565-open-file-chooser-in-webview

Espero te ayude :)

Comment: ¿el método onActivityResult y onActivityResultAboveL se declara dentro de la clase WebChromeClient() ?  Es que me indica que nunca será usada y por otro lado ¿ la variable uploadMessage donde se declara y de que tipo es ?

Comment: Por otro lado solo abre el directorio de archivos de imágenes. Debería dejar elegir en imágenes, documentos, crear foto..

Comment: Hola! Nop, se declara al nivel de tu activity que contiene el WebView, y la variable uploadMessage es te tipo ValueCallback<Uri[]>, y se declara al nivel de tu activity también. :)

Comment: Esto es un ejemplo para imágenes, si quieres abrir imagen, en el setType se especifica el tipo. Pero por ejemplo cualquier tipo podrías agregarle "*/*" como type.

Comment: En los enlaces que mencioné, puedes encontrar diversas implementaciones. Te sugiero revisarlas :)

Comment: Y el uploadMessageAboveL es del mismo tipo o tipo ValueCallback<Uri>

Comment: Al final funciona pero hay que declarar 3 variables de esta manera:  private ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMessage; private ValueCallback<Uri[]> uploadMessageAboveL; private final static int FILE_CHOOSER_RESULT_CODE = 1;

Comment: No doy aun por terminada la pregunta ya que debería permitirme subir otros tipos de archivos eligiendo alguna opción como  en HTML5 que me dejaría seleccionar una acción de entre estas:  Camara, VideoCamara, Grabadora de Voz, Mis Archivos, Galeria y Archivos.

Comment: Haz considerado que algunas de esas cosas no tienen directamente que ver con el input file?, me refiero a que estas preguntando sobre como obtener tanto camara como videocamara como grabadora de voz, etc, recuerda que el input file es para seleccionar archivos que ya tienes, no para usar archivos que no posees, por ejemplo para usar la grabadora de voz se requiere un comportamiento extra no especificado en la pregunta y que no viene con el input file, hasta donde se te deberia dejar usar todas las opciones anteriormente mencionadas excepto la grabadora de voz, la cual iria aparte.

Comment: Desde el input file todo lo que haz mencionado es seleccionable directamente, excepto la grabadora de voz, la grabadora de voz es algo que debe implementarse por aparte (lo se porque tengo un proyecto en el que lo he intentado, pero no hay opciones de voz), toca usar opciones nativas de javascript como MediaCapture para usar grabaciones de voz, para el caso de video e imagenes no necesitas MediaCapture, con el input file basta, puesto que lo probe y efectivamente me deja usar la camara para tomar tanto video como imagenes, solo debes especificar mas tipos (como lo dijo @rguzman).